# Java-script nodejs in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, systemjs

First of all I'm not skilled with JavaScript, I know basics but JS nowadays gets really confusing and for someone that is not in "JS loop" finding correct info is hard.

The question is:

I want to use google protocol buffers in web browser. The problem is that I can't load it into browser due to issue with:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require Global Code — js_pb.js:11`

As far as I know this is nodejs function.

`js_pb.js` is generated class from proto file by protoc using commonjs `--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary`.

So I googled and it seams like `systemjs` or `requirejs` is the way to go (to load nodejs javascript into web browser).

Added this to the html:

```
<!-- Load system js -->

<script src="./system.js"></script>
<script src="./extras/named-register.js"></script>
<script src="./extras/amd.js"></script>
<script src="./extras/use-default.js"></script>

<script type="systemjs-importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "google-protobuf": "./google-protobuf.js"
  }
}
</script>

<script type="systemjs-module" src="./js_pb.js"></script>

<script>
    <!-- var message = new proto.poc.MsgPoc(); -->    
    <!-- import {proto.poc.MsgPoc} from './js_poc_pb.js'; -->
```

Unfortunately `<script type="systemjs-module" src="./js_pb.js"></script>` also return issue with `required` missing.

*My question is*:

- How to properly use `systemjs` to load that java script into web browsers without need of packaging or bundling JS ?

or more general question

- How to load java-script that contains nodejs functions (`require` etc.) into web-browser without packaging all dependences into single JS (bundle like webpack)?

Thanks for reply in advance
Regards